# Why can I not share a Power BI report outside my organization?

Tags: powerpivot, powerbi

Power BI doesn't allow users to share reports outside the organization. This is severely limiting and makes me wonder how I'm supposed to create a Power BI solution for my customers.[image]

Why is this? And what is the preferred method for setting up my customers with Power BI?

Comment: Microsoft is currently working on this feature. You can vote for the feature to give higher priority to it here: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/6872640-share-with-external-users-outside-my-organisation Also, you can take Microsoft's survey they released a few days ago. They're trying to better understand the use cases for sharing externally: http://www.instant.ly/s/4HXvb/nav#p/30d40

Comment: Hi @PtotheBZZ were you ever able to share outside of your organization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vote for this [feature](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/6872640-share-with-external-users-outside-my-organisation). **Edit: this feature is now supported.**

Alternatives would be publishing a public content pack like Salesforce does so it appears under the Get Data menu. Or sending your external people a Power BI Desktop file they can upload to their Power BI. Or you could provision users in your domain for your external people and have them log into your tenant.

Or if you want to host an Analysis Services model and let external people see it in Power BI [here](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2015/10/22/power-bi-analysis-services-connector-and-azure-active-directory-domain-services) is an option.

Or if you prefer to use Azure Analysis Services then you can invite external users using B2B and they can consume in their own Power BI tenant. See the walkthrough [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/invite-guest-users-to-your-azure-analysis-services-by-using-b2b/).